# Python threading and multiproccessing modules have unexpected results in Windows

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing

I have created an application that has a simple GUI implemented in TKinter and with the press of a button it calls a python script that does some calculations. So, I have two files, one GUI.py and one Calculations.py. While the whole application works great in Ubuntu, I tried to migrate it in Windows and got some unexpected results. On GUI.py, at the point I call the Calculations, I also create a window with a progress bar and through a queue I check the progress of the algorithm. The structure at the point I call the Calculations is this:

GUI.py

```
import Calculations as calc

class OptimizationGUI:
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        ...
    def start_calcs(self):
        self.queue = Queue()    #pass a queue object for returning the results
        self.calcs = threading.Thread(target=calc.main, args = (self.queue,...))
        self.calcs.daemon = True
        self.working_window = Toplevel()   
        self.pgb = ttk.Progressbar(self.working_window, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')

        self.calcs.start()
        self.master.after(1000, self.check_queue)

     def check_queue(self):
        if self.optimization.is_alive():
           ... #do some calculations with the queue and show them in window
            self.master.after(1000, self.check_queue)
        else:
            self.working_window.destroy()
            self.show_final_result()
root = Tk()
my_gui = OptimizationGUI(root)
root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

The Calculations.py structure is this:

```
def main(queue,...)
    ...
#more functions and calculations that include spawning proccesses like this:
def heavy_calcs_proccesses():
    for i in range(core_number):
        recv_end, send_end = Pipe(False)
        p = Process(target=estimate_fitness_function, args=(...))
        jobs.append(p)
        pipe_list.append(recv_end)
        p.start()

    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()
    result_list = [x.recv() for x in pipe_list]
    return result_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Well, as I said before, the program works great in Ubuntu. Now in Windows what happens is this: When I press the "Run" button(the one that goes in the start_calcs function and starts the thread), along with the progressbar window, another master window(the main of my app) shows! The progress bar has completely no progress. Also, there are no calculations going on (I can tell that because no other cores show in task manager). There are some initial calculations from my Calculations.py script but I suppose that when it reaches the point of spawning more processes, for some reason it stops. So in Windows it has two issues: one with the threading module in GUI.py and one with the processes in Calculations.py. All I can guess is that it's a multiprocessing-multithreading issue but can't figure out what.

Comment: Have you tried `multiprocessing.freeze_support()`? I had a similar problem with Tkinter and Windows lately and this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Without all of the code presented, it's hard to say what the problem actually is. Here is something to look for. The symptom of the extra *master* window could indicate you have more than one `root.mainloop()` in your application, and there can only be one call to it. Other behaviors you described *could* be caused by this same issue.

Comment: @RonNorris: calling `root.mainloop()` more than once won't create additional windows.

Comment: you need to move the creation of `root` and `my_gui` and the calling of `root.mainloop()` inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block

Comment: please create a [mcve]. Your calling `mainloop` _before_ the check for `__name__` looks suspect since it will run (and thus, create  windows) in every process, but I can't run the code you posted.

Comment: @BryanOakley. Thanks for catching that calling root.mainloop() more than once doesn't create additional windows. Meant to say calling `Tk()` more than once.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you that fixed it!

Comment: @tzoukritzou the reason you need to do that has to do with how new processes are spawned. The gist of it is that the child process imports the `__main__` file as a library, so creating new processes outside the `if __name__ ...` block can basically create an infinite loop of "child process" -> "import" -> "child process" -> "import"... Python is smart enough to not fork bomb your computer, and will stop itself, but it can't fix the underlying problem itself. Putting the process creation in the "if main" block prevents that block from being run during import (only runs on main thread).